# how to create Custom action menu with animation

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, action-menu, floating-action-menu

I want to create custom action menu with animation in android like given Image below Please guide me for best solution Thanks In advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use this library instead it will work like charm.

[Yalantis Context Menu](https://github.com/Yalantis/Context-Menu.Android)

he explained wery well all steps it will fulfill your required functionality